# Having issues working with Nesting Associations in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, associations, sequelize.js

Having some trouble wrapping my brain around associations in Sequelize and Node.js. This is for a simple API that I'm putting together (no front end).

I'm trying to do a simple One to Many Association between a Customer and Address Model.

```
const Customer = sequelize.define('Customer', { /* stuff */ });
const Address = sequelize.define('Address', { /* stuff */ });

Customer.hasMany(Address);
Address.belongsTo(Customer);
```

My intention is to return a customer object with a list of associated addresses, like so:

```
{
    customer: {
      name: "Customer Name",
      // more customer fields...
      addresses: [
        { /* address fields */ },
        { /* address fields */ },
      ]
    }
}
```

In my controller, I'm doing the following thus far:

```
 Customer
   .findById(id)
   .then(customer => {
     customer.getAddresses()
       .then(addresses => {
         response.json({
           customer: customer,
           addresses: addresses,
         });
       });
   });
```

Which returns:

```
{
    customer: {
      name: "Customer Name",
      // more customer fields...
    },
    addresses: [
      { /* address fields */ },
      { /* address fields */ },
    ]
}
```

Any advice would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `include` the associated model in your fetch:

```
Customer
  .findById(id, {
     include: [{
       model: Address
     }]
  })
  .then(customer => {
    response.json({customer});
  });
```

See [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html) for more info.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This works exactly as I want. I looked at that page all day and couldn't seem to get this to work right.

One thing I also figured out is by adding `as: 'addresses'` in the model and the fetch, I was able to keep the syntax I wanted too.